# ASP.NET MVC AJAX to browser

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

How can I `debug/check` packets sent to browser from VS (ajax answers)? Is there a simple/clear way using the browser `/ visual studio / sniffer` ?
I use Chrome debugger to see what browser sends to the application, but in the same I can't find how to check response to that ajax call.
I would like to check the full packets ingoing/outgoing browser-side while debugging code (local server).
Could someone please assist me on doing that?

Edit : i would like to check the whole packets, not just the ajax calls with parameters.

Edit 2 : Network tab tells me the browser outgoing packets, for the initial ongoing it displays info but i can't find a way for the AJAX answers.
Maybe Wireshark configured on localhost?

Comment: Use the Network tab of your browser tools to inspect the Response

Comment: Use the [network tab in Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network) or [download and use Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

Comment: [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (`Console` or `Network` tabs) is your best chance in Firefox

Comment: i'm valuating Fiddler, FireBug and Wireshark, i'll post the solution